# Left-side pvalue for linear regression's constant in statsmodel

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression, statsmodels, p-value

I am testing multiple null hypotheses. I am using the following code and I realized that the P-values I got are two-tailed P-values for the t-stats of the params.

I would like to get the pvalue for the null hp -- > h0: constant of regression <= 0 (left tail test for constant of regression)

Is there anyone who knows out to set up the following test?

Here below the code:

import statsmodels.api as sm

y=np.array(excess_return_fund, dtype=float)

x=np.array(two, dtype=float)

model_p1 = sm.OLS(y, x).fit(cov_type='HAC', cov_kwds={'maxlags':1})

model.append(model_p1)

I thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

statsmodels currently does not allow t_test in model to have an inequality alternative.

The workaround is to divide the p-value by 2, assuming the estimate and test statistic are in the correct tails.

Alternatively, for a single parameter you could use tvalue and recompute the p-value but using only one tail of normal or t distribution.

old open issue
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1193

Comment: Thanks Josef. Besides dividing by 2, would you be able to suggest another possible way? Another package that allow me to set H0: constant regression <= 0 ?

Comment: I think you can just use the results from the OLS in `_tstat_generic` https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/stats/weightstats.py#L614 (scipy also has ttests `from_stats`). Verify that two-sided is the same as the OLSResults.